# Solve: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I download the source code of a project and want to build it. But I met the NoClassDefFoundError, the error msg like:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/jaxws/JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

Seems the project uses cxf, so I went to http://cxf.apache.org/ ,downloaded binary source and include them in classpath:
[image]

but the error still there :-(

this is where project import JaxWsProxyFactoryBean

[image]

What should I do to let jax work correctly in this project? I am new to java.

Comment: After downloading the binary in tar.gz format, did you unzip that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look inside the directory that you downloaded, you will realize that it is an installation of cxf, not just a library.  You need to actually include the jar files that come with cxf in your project, not just the cxf home directory.

Take a look at `C:\Users\luyi\Downloads\apache-cxf-2.2.5\lib\WHICH_JARS`, this will have instructions on which jar files you need to include in your project, depending on what you want to do in your project.

Comment: Thank you I have solved it by add the jar files directly instead of add the dictionary that includes these jar files.